# Is it possible to unmerge Piecewise expressions?

Tags: piecewise

I have an expression involving Piecewise that I want to break into specific cases.  If I let Mathematica's simplification rules loose then it doesn't seem to pick up an obvious cancellation which can be simplified.  There doesn't seem to be a builtin way to do this so I'm left with awkward expression rewriting as the only solution.  For the specific case I'm interested, see below (update: text code).

```
IdxAssump=m ∈ Integers && m>= 0 && n ∈ Integers && n >= 0;

p = Piecewise[{{E^(-α Conjugate[α]) Abs[α]^(-2 m + 2 n) n! Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[-m, 1 - m + n, Abs[α]^2]^2/m!, m < n}}, 
              E^(-α Conjugate[α]) Abs[α]^(2 (m - n)) m! Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[-n, 1 + m - n, Abs[α]^2]^2/ n!]

FullSimplify[p /. {α -> 0}, IdxAssump]

p2=Piecewise[Append[p[[1]],{FullSimplify[p[[2]]/.{m->n}],m==n}],p[[2]]]

FullSimplify[p2/.{α->0},IdxAssump]
```

[image: Mathematica output]

So the question is, can the automatic merging of conditions be picked apart?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. Please take a moment to have a look at the overview here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help . In order to improve the chances for getting good answers, please post code that can be copy-pasted into Mathematica, as users are not likely to re-type your screenshot.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: I have updated the question with copyable input text.  I found no help on how to make properly formatted output text so I just put an updated image.